# Memoizing PHP/MySQL functions

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have a function that is slow because of MySQL queries.
The function will return the same result as long as certain MySQL tables remain unchanged.
What is the simplest way to "memoize" such a function in PHP/MySQL?

**edit:**
What I would like to see is:

- Something like a table hash/last modified date for a table from MqSQL.
- Something from PHP side being clever enough to figure out what tables a function may access and cache/retrieve the results if approriate.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simple_%28philosophy%29

Comment: Nothing is "Simple" in programming unless it's quick and dirty and you usually DONT want quick and dirty programming

Comment: It's "simplest". If you think that "simpler" solutions are quick and dirty, write in assembly.

Comment: I would first look at the SQL queries. Use `explain` to find out why they are slow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are most likely looking for caching methods of data.

Here are a few methods that may be of interest:

**memcached/APC**

If you have access to a host that supports this, go for it. This is the single, fastest way to store and retrieve data today.

**Reference**: http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.memcached.php

---

**File caching**

You can use the file library in PHP to save data to a file and retrieve it whenever required. This may be useful for Javascript data as well as you can dynamically load the .js file on-demand.

**Reference**: http://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.filesystem.php

---

**SQL caching**

You can also store your results on a separate table (assuming you are using a complex operation that is expensive and not pulling it off a single table already) for easy read/write access.

**Reference**: http://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.pdo-mysql.php

---

It may be in your interest to look at `cronjobs` in order to delete your cached data over time as well (in order to save space or update the cache).

**Reference**: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cron

Enjoy and good luck!

Answer (score 1):

Why not just cache the result of the queries and clear the cache if those certain tables change?

Comment: how would you know if the tables have changed?  supposedly without running yet another query?

Comment: I assume he has the application that is making the changes to the tables so he can clear the cache if he is updating those tables in his update functions.

Answer (score 1):

Well first you could simply store results in a semlf made 'cache' whilst processing the result the first time. Then, when the same query is to be fired again you simply read the result from  the cache. But this only works if you KNOW that nothing has changed in the tables. Do you ?

Apart from that: the mysql RDMBS is quite good at caching itself. So usually firing the same query a second time will get a reply much faster anyway. Isn't that enough ?

Answer (score 1):

On my side, i use a custom MVC framework i built and each time i call a SELECT based function i will look in the cache if i have that result already processed and simply return it:

```
public static function getProductsByCategory(Activis_Catalog_Models_Category $category, array $except = array(), $limitedToActivation = true){

    //If the cache contains the request, return it
    if(isset(self::$__resultCache['getProductsByCategory'][md5(serialize(func_get_args()))])){ return self::$__resultCache['getProductsByCategory'][md5(serialize(func_get_args()))]; }

     ...... PROCESS THE FUNCTION NORMALLY ....

    self::$__resultCache['getProductsByCategory'][md5(serialize(func_get_args()))] = $objects;
    return $objects;
```

This will be a simple caching mechanism that allows you to cache your data (in this case objects) and return them if the same function call is made again later.

In the event you have UPDATE/DELETE/INSERT functionnality in your model, you should remember to CLEAR the "$cache" or else you will return incorrect data that was changed.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [Cachalot](https://github.com/ihor/Cachalot). The code will look like that:

```
$cache = new \Cachalot\ApcCache();
$products = $cache->getCached([$productRepository, 'findByCategory'], ['cars']);
```

Different back-ends are supported: Apc, Xcache, Memcached, Redis, Couchbase.